# Server shuts down (Error 503) on deployed environment after login. on development evironment works as expected

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating an application using NET 6 LTS and Angular 14. On the development environment (using IIS express) the app behaves normally. However when I deploy the application (release) on Windows 2019 and IIS 10, right after the login the server returns error 503. The application pool and the site have appropriate permissions. (I even tried to allow everyone with full access to verify it).

below is the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TheFile.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

and the appsettings.json file is the following

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "<connection string values>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "<connection string values>",
          "sinkOptionsSection": {
            "tableName": "EasymintLog",
            "schemaName": "dbo",
            "autoCreateSqlTable": true
            //"batchPostingLimit": 50,
            //"period": "0.00:00:05"
          },
          //"restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning",
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "disableTriggers": true,
            "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
            "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties", "TimeStamp", "Message" ],
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "UserId",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 50
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ControllerAction",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 10
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "Request",
                "DataType": "nvarchar"
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "Response",
                "DataType": "nvarchar"
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "StatusCode",
                "DataType": "int",
                "AllowNull": true
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "LogDate",
                "DataType": "datetime2",
                "AllowNull": true
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "ClientAddress",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "AllowNull": true,
                "DataLength": 15
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "InnerException",
                "DataType": "nvarchar"
              }
            ],
            "id": { "nonClusteredIndex": true },
            "level": {
              "columnName": "Severity",
              "storeAsEnum": false
            },
            "timeStamp": {
              "columnName": "Timestamp"
              //"convertToUtc": true
            },
            "logEvent": {
              "excludeAdditionalProperties": true,
              "excludeStandardColumns": true
            },
            "message": { "columnName": "Message" },
            "exception": { "columnName": "Exception" }
            //"messageTemplate": { "columnName": "Template" }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "NextStepNG": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  //SMTP settings
  //"SMTP": {
  //  "Host": "",
  //  "From": "NextStep Notifications",
  //  "Port": 587, //25,
  //  "UseSSL": true,
  //  "Username": "",
  //  "Password": ""
  //},
}
```

I don't know if there is an issue with the app startup.cs file.
Which is the following...

```
using AutoMapper;
using Duende.IdentityServer.Services;
using IdempotentAPI.Cache.DistributedCache.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using IdempotentAPI.Cache.FusionCache.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NextStepNG.BusinessLogic.CommonBLs;
using NextStepNG.BusinessLogic.EshopBLs;
using NextStepNG.Data;
using NextStepNG.Data.EFCore.Common;
using NextStepNG.Data.EFCore.Company;
using NextStepNG.Data.EFCore.Eshop;
using NextStepNG.Data.EFCore.Organization;
using NextStepNG.Data.EFCore.Person;
using NextStepNG.Enums;
using NextStepNG.Models;
using NextStepNG.Services;
using NextStepNG.Utils.Common;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace NextStepNG
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                    }));

            services.AddDbContext<NEXTSTEPNGContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                    }));

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddIdempotentAPIUsingDistributedCache();

            //services.AddIdempotentAPIUsingFusionCache();
            //services.AddFusionCacheNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();            

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                // new key every 30 days
                options.KeyManagement.RotationInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);

                // announce new key 2 days in advance in discovery
                options.KeyManagement.PropagationTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);

                // keep old key for 7 days in discovery for validation of tokens
                options.KeyManagement.RetentionDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);

                // don't delete keys after their retention period is over
                options.KeyManagement.DeleteRetiredKeys = false;
            })
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Developer.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.developer.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Easymint.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.easymint.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Administrator.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.administrator.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Manager.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.manager.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.Tester.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.tester.ToString()));

                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationEnum.Roles.User.ToString(), policy =>
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AuthorizationEnum.Claims.user.ToString()));
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc();

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddScoped<LoggingActionFilter>();

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));

            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddScoped<CountryRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<LocaleRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<RolesRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<UserSettingsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<OrganizationLocaleRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<OrganizationsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<PersonsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<OrganizationBanksRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<AddressesRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<BanksRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<FullDetailsInfoRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<CompaniesRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<CompanyBankAccountsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<CompanyDetailsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<CompanyIRSRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<CustomerDetailsInfoRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<OrganizationDetailsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<OrganizationIRSRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<OrganizationBankAccountRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<UsersManagementBL>();
            services.AddScoped<EmployeeManagementBL>();
            services.AddScoped<EmployeeManagementRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<PersonsBL>();
            services.AddScoped<EshopLicenseTypesRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<RepairsRepository>();
            //services.AddScoped<EshopUsersBL>();
            services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseForwardedHeaders();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseForwardedHeaders();
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseXContentTypeOptions();
            app.UseReferrerPolicy(r => r.StrictOriginWhenCrossOrigin());
            app.UseXDownloadOptions();
            app.UseXRobotsTag(r => r
                .NoFollow()
                .NoIndex());
            app.UseXXssProtection(x => x.Enabled());
            //app.UseMiddleware<StackifyMiddleware.RequestTracerMiddleware>(); //debug only
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //nwebsec section
            //app.UseCsp(options => options.DefaultSources(s => s.Self()
            //.CustomSources("https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/19.2.6/css/dx.light.css",
            //    "https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/19.2.6/css/icons/dxicons.woff",
            //    "https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/19.2.6/css/icons/dxicons.woff2",
            //    "https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/19.2.6/css/icons/dxicons.ttf")));

            app.UseCsp(options => options
                .FrameAncestors(f => f.Self()));
            //.ScriptSources(f => f.Self())
            //.ReportUris(r => r.Uris("/reports")));

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{operation}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                //To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                //see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501


                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    //spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                    //comment the line below before deployment
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What should I check and how to proceed ? Anyone faced the same issue before ?
Thank you in advance

I tried altering permissions and various settings in IIS based on the info I've found here and google. The result remained the same.

Based on the info I found on the windows event viewer it shows the following error

```
Category: Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.KeyManager
EventId: 0
SpanId: b248d52022677998
TraceId: 01ac174a5bdcbb9ec7a8aec2e95a16be
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 80000042-0001-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /.well-known/openid-configuration

Error unprotecting key with kid FB30056547480314CDD1824BFB8D469F.

Exception: 
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {a6be54e5-5ff8-4fb4-90aa-eb89fa686bc0} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedData)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.DataProtectionKeyProtector.Unprotect(SerializedKey key) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/KeyManagement/DataProtectionKeyProtector.cs:line 56
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.KeyManagement.KeyManager.<GetKeysFromStoreAsync>b__20_0(SerializedKey x) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/KeyManagement/KeyManager.cs:line 426
```

Please help, as I haven't encountered this before and I've deployed .NET core apps in the past with no issue.

PS. the app is run locally and there is no issue with firewall or anti virus

Comment: Web apps on IIS are accessing resources (key ring in your case) differently, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 If you don't resolve that exception, the application keeps crashing and 503 error is expected.

Comment: I've already made the appropriate changes like the article says. Most likely the issue resides in the web.config file. This is the updated configuration file that was used.

looks like the following line was the culprit. It had a different port value
         <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44374" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you get this error in the logs, then that means that the Data Protection API is not properly configured.

*The key {a6be54e5-5ff8-4fb4-90aa-eb89fa686bc0} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning*

The issue is that the encryption key is re-generated on each deployment if not properly configured and changing the encryption key means that all previously issued cookies are no longer valid.

The error you get above means that the key to decrypt the session cookie was not found.

I did blog about data protection here for some time ago
https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en

The picture below outlines how you can configure the data protection API.

[image]

Comment: I looking at it right now. will let you know ASAP. Thank you in advance

Comment: Most likely, the issue was located in the applicationHost.config file, where the app pool was set to the defaultAppPool. I'm trying it right now and I will let you know

Comment: The error should hove any anything to do with app pools or IIS, this is an ASP.NET Core configuration issue

Comment: true, but on the file mentioned above, the app pool was set to DefaultApp Pool, instead of the intended app pool, plus I did configure the ASP.NET core as per your advice. I'll reply ASAP

Comment: One question. Do you have to issue keys before deployment ? If so, is there a link I can follow ?

Comment: The Data Protection API can generate its own keys, if you only provide a way for to persist/store it., see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Feel free to approve my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I believe I managed to get it to work...I've upgraded all the necessary nugets and added data protection with db context persistence...i will know tomorrow

Comment: works like a charm still....no 503 errors....thanks...I'll keep in mind this and if something goes wrong then i'll know that's anything besides the issue mentioned regarding data protection !

Comment: I hate getting back to this question, but would it be possible to ask for a clarification ? Although the fix above works on the production environment. I still get error 503 when I debug the application using IIS Express. Any ideas on where to look ?

Comment: I would start by digging into the extensive logging provided by the ASP.NET core. In general, the Data protection API should not return 503. IF you are on IIS, you might catch the exceptions in the Windows event logs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Again the error is regarding the key not found in the key ring. I persist the keys in the db context. I have created a table for the keys, following the instructions from microsoft. I've also configured my startup.cs file and set the application name where i set the service "AddDataProtection()". Should I check anything else (besides logs and exceptions). The IIS is configured properly and I allow the loading of the user application profile in the app pool.

Comment: You need to figure out what is causign the exception, see the ASP.NET Core logs or windows event log.